# I want to create a chrome extension that obtains all the links in a page and displays them.

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, google-chrome

I want to create a chrome extension that obtains all the links in a page and displays them.
Can I do it using the DOM model in javascript? or do I have to use xmlHttpRequest(AJAX)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions have full access to the DOM so just grab them using Javascript will work just fine. I can recommend experimenting with it using the TamperMonkey extension which will shorten your roundtrips when testing stuff.

Comment: But using DOM, I am only able to access the current working HTML doc. How do I access the page's source?
content.document.getElementsByTagName("a") doesn't seem to work for me.